# Recent Query in Training

Tags: watson-discovery

I'm training Watson Discovery through the dashboard however I need more information about user queries, the dashboard only shows the user query text e.g " I want customer care number" or "continue" as shown in the picture, while I want to know more about the user query: 
1.The timestamp of the query.
2.Channel that used Watson Discovery e.g Slack, Twitter.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want fine grained training in Discovery, you might want to use the APIs. Discovery training interface is basic and doesn't allow to see any custom information or even to give a customised rating score. It takes 0 and 10 by default and you can't change it for the interface.

However you can use the APIs to give any custom training range and also you can extract all the training data that's trained into the service.

Let me also inform that the training data has to be of a certain format JSON. You can mention the NLQ, filter, time, answerId to train for that question etc. I'm not sure you can add a custom field to it like the platform from where that training was given. But you can try giving it and if it works, then both of us would learn something new.